# Magnetic field along the axis of a solenoid - Can I find it this way?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

I know how to find the magnetic field of a current carrying loop along its axis. The result is the following :

$$B=\frac{μ_0IR^2}{2(R^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$ 
z is the axis, R the distance of the loop from the axis

Can I turn this into an integral and find the total B along a solenoid if its loops are very close to each other? I get a good result but comparing it to other results I miss the $n=N/L$ where L is the length of the solenoid and N the loops.

Should I alter $I$ in my equation? Also, shall I make dz show up or do I just integrate with the proper limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of the solenoid is $L$ and it has $N$ turns then the turns per unit length $n = \frac N L$.

[image]

Between the origin at the centre of the solenoid and  position $z$ from the centre there are $m = n z$ turns.

The number of turns between $z$ and $z+dz$ is $n\,dz$ so the contribution to the magnetic field at the centre of the solenoid of this group of coils is

$$dB=\frac{μ_0IR^2}{2(R^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \, n \, dz$$

If you now integrate between $z= - \frac L2$ and $z= + \frac L2$ and make the approximation that $\frac L 2 \gg R$ you will get the $B=\mu_{\rm o} n I$ relationship.

---

Alternatively you could set up a summation with the $z$ step equal to the separation of the coils $\frac L N$.
This is more difficult as you will probably have to do the summation numerically rather than find a nice algebraic formula.

Comment: Great explanation. L/2 and -L/2 is for the center . I did this for a random position on the z axis. For a random z I split the integral into 2 parts . One for the points above z and one for those below. Then my lower limits are both zero and the upper limits are L/2 - |z| and L-|z| respectively. Then I sum them for the total B. Do you think that is correct ?

Comment: I think that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The differential unit is a volume along $dZ$. The amount of loops in that volume is $\frac{N}{L}*dZ$. Hence $dB=B(loop)*\frac{N}{L}*dZ$. $dB$ varies along $Z$ because the field of the loops varies along $Z$, but the amount of loops in the differential volume is always $\frac{N}{L}*dZ$.

Answer (score 0):

With very good approximation the solenoid can be treated as a toroid with a very large radius.

For a given toroid with internal radius $a$ and external radius $b$, using Ampère's law, it's easy to see that
$B = \frac{\mu_0Ni}{2\pi r}, a < r < b$.

Now, if we write $n = \frac{N}{2\pi R}$, where $R$ is the average radius $\frac{a+b}{2}$, we get $B = \frac{\mu_0niR}{r}$, $a < r < b$.

For large distances, as in a solenoid, $R \approx r$, so we have $B \approx  \mu_0ni$. Even though the  field "scapes" through its ends and the empty spaces between the loops, the field inside it is way stronger than outside, making that approximation reasonable.